# React - Do something only after state change (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Throughout my application I am modifying state through `useState()`, for example:

```
const [question, setQuestion] = useState('')

const updateQuestionHandler = () => {
  let honestQuestion = 'is this a race condition?'
  setQuestion(honestQuestion)
  console.log(question)  // Returns => '' or the previous state, why isn't the updated state returned instead?
}

return (
  <div> 
    <p> { question } </p> // This is generally updated correctly, after the button click below
    <button onClick={() => updateQuestionHandler()}> Click to update question </button>
  </div> 
)
```

What is happening above is, once I update state with `setQuestion(variable)`, the state gets updated (eventually). How can I ensure that the state has been updated and is safe for reference after setting it?

You can see where I try to `console.log()` the updated state, right after setting it, the previous or old state gets returned. I could instead `console.log(honestQuestion)` , is that the correct thing to do? I feel like I should be using state as the single source of truth.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous. See the posted answer.

Comment: Simply put, updating state is asynchronous.  The linked duplicate goes into more detail as to why.  But to answer the question, where you are currently using `console.log` you would indeed log `honestQuestion` if that's the information you want to see on the console and that's the time at which you want to see it.

Comment: The attached "duplicate" uses the class based `this.setState({})` which allows callbacks, which would allow me to accomplish what I was trying to do in the original question. Callbacks are not supported in `useState()` hooks. Its valuable that you mentioned updating state is asynchronous, I appreciate that - but the linked post doesn't answer the question of "how" I safely use the updated state after a change with hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something after a hook state was updated you need to use a `useEffect` and pass the state to the dependencies array

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(question)
},[question])
```

This will only run after every time the `question` state is updated.

Comment: This is valuable thanks. I looks like I need to alter the way I'm referencing state after a change. Meaning, instead of directly calling `console.log(updatedState)` inside the function that is updating it, create a separate function instead, that only gets run by `useEffect()` after a state change. From there, I can "safely" rely on `question` or whatever `updatedState` to have been updated

Comment: @bruh you are correct.